# How to show/hide view with animation when bottom sheet state change in android?

Tags: android, animation, bottom-sheet

I had tried to add fade `in/out animation` on `view` when `BottomSheet state` changes. I want to show green part when drag down and red part when drag up with animation.

[image: Image when bottomsheet collapsed]

[image: Image when bottomsheet expanded]